# GitHub Actions: shared cached gradle dependencies

Tags: gradle, caching, github-actions

I'm trying to implement caching for my workflow using **actions/cache@v2** (https://github.com/actions/cache) action.

I have a workflow which runs on pull requests.My project has tons of dependencies so it would be a great build time improvement if I could re-use artifacts, downloaded previously. After successful run artifacts got cached **within this pull request/branch** and can be re-used on next runs for this pull request:

```
Cache restored successfully

Cache restored from key: Linux-823bfbee4d05185dedf13d718e8e4ff4933074565b84dd636e19434372154c6a-8331f72d4c267e28baf5311f561dc9f09f1813899db5fd4929c70715b85b2934-45275122110c339513af5e3da3a953eed4a843d91a5d03cd48b8a26988749289
```

From this description: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows
I got an impression, that the cache (including gradle dependencies, like libraries etc), once downloaded, should be available for other branches based on my develop, after one of the PRs got merged:

```
A workflow can access and restore a cache created in the current branch, the base branch (including base branches of forked repositories), or the default branch (usually main). For example, a cache created on the default branch would be accessible from any pull request. Also, if the branch feature-b has the base branch feature-a, a workflow triggered on feature-b would have access to caches created in the default branch (main), feature-a, and feature-b.
```

But apparently, it doesn't work for me, I'm getting this for all the new PRs:

```
Run actions/cache@v2
Cache not found for input keys: Linux-823bfbee4d05185dedf13d718e8e4ff4933074565b84dd636e19434372154c6a-8331f72d4c267e28baf5311f561dc9f09f1813899db5fd4929c70715b85b2934-45275122110c339513af5e3da3a953eed4a843d91a5d03cd48b8a26988749289
```

So I'm getting all the gradle dependencies downloaded, over and over again.

So my question is: is it possible to have the dependencies, once downloaded, be available from cache for all other branches/pull requests. If yes, can this be done using **actions/cache@v2** or shall I look to another tasks/tools?

Here's simplified version of my workflow:

```
name: build-pull-request
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - reopened
    branches:
      - '**'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  verify-pull-request-quality:
    name: Verify pull request

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Cancel previous runs of this workflow
        uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.9.1
        with:
          access_token: ${{ github.token }}
      - name: Check out ${{ github.ref }}
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Cache gradle dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        env:
          cache-name: cache-gradle-depedencies
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.gradle/caches
            ~/.gradle/wrapper
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*') }}-${{
            hashFiles('**/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties') }}-${{
            hashFiles('**/buildSrc/**/*.kt') }}
      - name: Run unit test
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
          build-root-directory: ${{env.working-directory}}
          arguments: assemble
```

Comment: I'd guess that your hashing of the buildSrc invalidates it (e.g. file timestamps). Instead you could let the [gradle-build-action](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-build-action#caching) do all of the caching for you.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure it's not getting unvalidated. I did an experiment: executed workflow on branch_a, then create a another branch_b from branch_a and tried to execute the workflow on branch_b -> caches were not available, but the caches were still valid on branch_a (and the workflow managed to pick them up)

Comment: In this [section](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-build-action#only-write-to-the-cache-from-the-default-branch) on caching, "GitHub cache entries are not shared between builds on different branches." It then discusses a workaround and they phrase it as if a Github restriction.

Answer (score 0):

you can change gradle cache location by setting cli args

here my config for ci github

- set cache

  ```
  - uses: actions/cache@v3
    with:
      path: |
        $HOME/.m2/repository
        ~/.m2/repository
        ./.gradle
        ./app/build
        ./build
        ./release
      key: gradle-${{ runner.os }}
      restore-keys: |
        gradle-${{ runner.os }}
        gradle-
  ```

call the gradle step

```
  - name: Generate Dictionary
    run: bash ./gradlew genDict --gradle-user-home .gradle
  - name: Build release APK
    run: bash ./gradlew assembleRelease --gradle-user-home .gradle
```

kill java processes before saving cache (post actions/cache)

```
  - name: kill java processes
    run: |
      wmic process where "name like '%java%'" delete
      taskkill /f /im jqs.exe
      taskkill /f /im javaw.exe
      taskkill /f /im java.exe
    continue-on-error: true
```

[full CI sample](https://github.com/dimaslanjaka/android-traffic-exchange/blob/6a656e3302dac1f620043f530844220c09c9772a/.github/workflows/android.yml#L1-L140)

all downloaded jars, build caches in folder `rootProject/.gradle`

cached looks like [image: cache result]